# White iPhone 4 vs. black iPhone 4

Tags: iphone

Other than the color, what exactly are the difference between the black and the white iPhone 4?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two changes that I've read about, both related to the color change but not just that the color is different:

1. The **rear camera** positioning has been slightly modified to reduce the amount of light that leaks into the area; it's said to be recessed slightly deeper into the device, though other reports indicate a slightly different casing. Makes sense, since the black glass and plastic would absorb light that the white glass and plastic would let through, likely causing washed-out pictures (or the software adjusting the white balance incorrectly, losing details in lighter and/or darker areas of the image).
2. Reports also indicate that the **proximity sensor** has been modified. Though it's quite possible, if the iPhone uses a capacitive proximity sensor such a change shouldn't be necessary (if it uses an infrared proximity sensor then the same light change issue would require a change). It seems more likely that the change was made for the **ambient light sensor** which is right next to the proximity sensor, since the ambient light sensor would have light change differences as well.

Other than the the phones are identical. The new one is no faster, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this gallery](http://www.theinfow.com/2011/04/comparison-between-black-iphone-4-and.html) for some comparison photos.

Answer (score -2):

Its supposed to be identical, [but 0.2mm thicker](http://www.pcworld.com/article/226774/white_iphone_4_is_thicker_than_black_model.html)

Comment: The thickness thing has pretty much been disproven. It turns out that, like most manufactured goods, all iPhones differ slightly in thickness. One report I read showed that much variation between 4 different black iPhones.

Comment: @Matthew: I would think that even the temperature of the phone would make a difference, when we are talking about variations as small as that.

Comment: @jason404 Agreed. 0.2mm is equivalent to the diameter of 1-2 human hairs.

Comment: All reports of this being systematically true seem to be false and due to errors in measurement and one time manufacturing variations rather than a systematic change in specifications.

Answer (score -2):

There is only a Color Difference between both devices.